# Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{3} + \sqrt{5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: minimal-polynomials, algebraic-numbers

Let $x = \sqrt[3]{3} + \sqrt{5}$
Notice that $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$
Then, $x^2 = (\sqrt[3]{3} + \sqrt{5})^2 = \sqrt[3]{3}^2 + 2\sqrt[3]{3}\sqrt{5} + 5$
Then, $x^3 - 5 = \sqrt[3]{3}^2 + 2\sqrt[3]{3}\sqrt{5}$

Or notice that $(x+y)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3$
Then, $x^3 = (\sqrt[3]{3} + \sqrt{5})^3 = 3 + 2\sqrt[3]{3}^2\sqrt{5} + 10\sqrt[3]{3} + 5\sqrt{5}$
Then, $x^3 - 3 = 2\sqrt[3]{3}^2\sqrt{5} + 10\sqrt[3]{3} + 5\sqrt{5}$

Which I think the degree of the minial polynomial of $x$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ should have a degree of $6$.
Which means the minimal polynomial can be written as $x^6 + a_5 x^5 + \cdots + a_0$ for some $a_5, ..., a_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$.
But I just don't how get it from both the ways I provide above.
Or that $\sqrt[3]{3} + \sqrt{5}$ is not algebraic. So, I can not write such minimal polynomial out algebraic ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing a degree 4 rational polynomial satisfying $f(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359054/constructing-a-degree-4-rational-polynomial-satisfying-f-sqrt2-sqrt3-0)

Comment: Well, it seem that compute $(\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt{5})^6$ will take a long time. So, I prefer the answer provided by @José Carlos Santos below. It saves a lot time for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt5$, then $\left(x-\sqrt5\right)^3=3$. In other words $x^3-3 \sqrt{5} x^2+15 x-5 \sqrt{5}-3=0$. But\begin{align}x^3-3 \sqrt{5} x^2+15 x-5 \sqrt{5}-3=0&\iff x^3+15x-3=(3x^2-5)\sqrt5\\&\implies(x^3+15x-3)^2=5(3x^2-5)^2\\&\iff x^6-15 x^4-6 x^3+375 x^2-90 x-116=0.\end{align}

Comment: We also need to show that the polynomial is irreducible. But I think we can directly prove that $[\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt{5}):\mathbb {Q}] =6$.

Answer (score 2):

Set of algebraic numbers form a field, so the sum of two algebraic numbers $\sqrt[3]{3} + \sqrt{5}$ is again an algebraic number.

To find the minimal polynomial, you want to continue in either of the two ways that you have started.

If it is the first way,
you have to take the suitable powers of $x^2-5$ and continue until getting a rational polynomial.

Comment: isn't 0 the minimal polynomial?